# How to push first element in array with Immutability Helpers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, immutable.js

I need to push first element in array as last.

The problem is it is a link to the object.

How to do it with with immutability helper.

My existing code is bellow.

```js
state = {

    table: [['', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', '']],
  }


appendRow = () => {
    
    let newTable = deepcopy(this.state.table);

    newTable.push(this.state.table[0].slice())

    this.setState({ table: newTable });
    

}
```

What I have with immutability helper I suggest not good

```js
 appendRow = () => {
    this.setState({ table: update(this.state.table, { $push: [this.state.table[0].slice()] }) });
  }
```

because I use `slice()` again.

How to do it better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `immutability.js` but for this purpose you can use `reduceRight`, which are a `pure function` from standard library, as follows:

```
table.reduceRight((a,e,i) => { i === 0 ? a.push(e) : a.unshift(e); return a }, []);
```

Inserting this in your example:

```
appendRow = () => {
    this.state.table.reduceRight((a,e,i) => { i === 0 ? a.push(e) : a.unshift(e); return a }, []);}
```